# phpmyadmin not displaying picture from database

Tags: windows, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a phpmyadmin setup and all is fine and well but I can't seem to get the interface to display the pictures from the database, What could be the issue ?

I've enabled the **gd2** extension in php , it doesn't seem to have solved the issue

Here is an image:
[Image not displaying in tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqfSK.png)

Here is a snapshot of that column's configuration
[Column configuration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B2We.png),
[Column configuration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoZzQ.png)

Interestingly enough when I try to open the image in a new tab this comes up: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HSiG.png)

Is this a possible bug or I'am I just and idiot ?

Comment: Let's see the relevant code.

Comment: Code ? You mean the Error code? [Right Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HSiG.png)

Comment: Perhaps in `transformation_wrapper.php` -- there is a "cn" without a $ in front.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably because you are not using the correct version of any dependency.

Try to Look for the right dependencies, but don't worry you're not an idiot.

Comment: How can I check can you please elaborate? 


I'm using my phpmyadmin 5.0.1 all the extensions came default with php version 7.4.2

Comment: where do you have phpmyadmin installed? linux?

Comment: Or another idea is that you could try to install a more stable version since it was released on 10/2020 which is very early.

Comment: I have it installed on Microsoft IIS7.5 on a windows 7 box if you surggests that this version is too early does this mean it's possibly a bug ?

Comment: Yes posible it was a bug

Answer (score 0):

There are no "pictures" in the database, only numbers, dates, and strings.  Some of those "strings" may represent images or videos, but it is up to the client to interpret them as such.  phpmyadmin is a generic client for fetching only numbers, dates, and strings.

PHP, as distinct from phpmyadmin, is a programming language that has plugins for talking to MySQL and for generating HTML code that could include `<img ...>` tags.  From that, a web server and web browser can display images.

phpmyadmin is written in PHP, but now *you* have to write a client in PHP (or something else) to get images displayed.